# How to programmatically create a commit with Rugged?

Tags: ruby, git, libgit2, rugged

I am trying to programmatically create a commit to an existing repository using [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) (the Ruby binding of [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/)). I have tried to follow the documentation provided in the Rugged [README](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/blob/development/README.md), but I think it doesn't quite match up with the current state of the codebase. I keep getting errors when I try running the following code:

```
require 'rugged'
# Create an instance of the existing repository
repo = Rugged::Repository.new('/full/path/to/repo')
# grab the current Time object for now
curr_time = Time.now
# write a new blob to the repository, hang on to the object id
oid = repo.write("Some content for the this blob - #{curr_time}.", 'blob')
# get the index for this repository
index = repo.index
# add the blob to the index
index.add(:path => 'newfile.txt', :oid => oid, :mode => 0100644)
curr_tree = index.write_tree(repo)
curr_ref = 'HEAD'
author = {:email=>'email@email.com',:time=>curr_time,:name=>'username'}
new_commit = Rugged::Commit.create(repo,
    :author => author,
    :message => "Some Commit Message at #{curr_time}.",
    :committer => author,
    :parents => [repo.head.target],
    :tree => curr_tree,
    :update_ref => curr_ref)
```

The current error I am getting says that there is something wrong with the `index.add` line. It says `TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Fixnum)`.

Any help on better understanding how to create a new commit with rugged would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I just updated `Rugged 0.16.0` to `Rugged 0.18.0.gh.de28323` by running `gem install --prerelease rugged`. The code I detailed above seems to work now. I am not sure why it didn't work with 0.16.0. This person seemed to have the same problem which they detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659487/535590).

Comment: what is the line number?

Comment: It is breaking at the line with `index.add`.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I read index.add file

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're passing in `nil` to `index.add` where it doesn't accept one, and the error in that line is just a symptom of failing to check for errors earlier. The second parameter to `repo.write` should be a symbol, not a string, so it's most likely returning `nil` to signal an error. Passing `:blob` instead of `'blob'` should fix it.

You can take a look at https://github.com/libgit2/docurium/blob/master/lib/docurium.rb#L115-L116 and surrounding code which we're using to generate libgit2's own documentation.

Comment: I was originally giving `repo.write` a symbol (`:blob`) as the second argument, but then it would error on that line claiming it didn't recognize the symbol. However, when I changed it to `'blob'`, it worked. The `oid` isn't nil. I am basing that off of the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386044/comparing-2-commits-in-rugged?rq=1).

Comment: Rugged has accepted a symbol for a very long time. If it doesn't, then there's something quite wrong in the setup. Make sure you have the latest rugged.

Comment: See my update. Also, I got the code above to work with both `'blob'` and `:blob`. Not sure why that is. Any ideas?